# sorting an array of objects by some property without using collections that is doing manually

Tags: java, sorting, object, oop

**In this i am trying to sort an array of objects by their id's whose age > 30 but compiler is giving error in searchVoteByAge function in while loop :

`while((j>-1)&& (v[j].getVoterId() > key.getVoterId()))`   in this line **

> error :Exception in thread "main"
> java.lang.NullPointerException       at algorithms.Dijstra_algo.searchVoterByAge(Dijstra_algo.java:77)       at
> algorithms.Dijstra_algo.main(Dijstra_algo.java:55)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Demo
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    Voter voter[]=new Voter[4];
    for(int i=0;i<voter.length;i++){
        int v_id=sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        String v_nme=sc.next();
        sc.nextLine();
        int v_age=sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        boolean is_vote_casted=sc.nextBoolean();
        sc.nextLine();
        String constituency=sc.next();
        sc.nextLine();
        voter[i]=new Voter();
        voter[i].setVoterId(v_id);
        voter[i].setVoterName(v_nme);
        voter[i].setVoterAge(v_age);
        voter[i].setVoteCasted(is_vote_casted);
        voter[i].setConstituency(constituency);
    }
    String cons=sc.next();
    int c=findTotal(voter,cons);
    if(c>0)
      System.out.println(c);
    else
      System.out.println("No votes Casted");
    
    Voter v[]=searchVoterByAge(voter);
    if(v.length > 0){
        for(Voter obj: v){
            System.out.println(obj.getVoterId());
        }
    }
    else
     System.out.println("No such voters");
}
private static Voter[] searchVoterByAge(Voter[] voters) {
    Voter v[]=new Voter[voters.length];
    int k=0,f=0;
    for(Voter obj:voters) {
        if(obj.getVoterAge()<30) {
            v[k]=new Voter();
            v[k++]=obj;
            f=1;
        }
    }
    for(int i=1;i<v.length;i++) {
        Voter key=v[i];
        int j=i-1;
        while((j>-1)&& (v[j].getVoterId() > key.getVoterId())) {
            v[j+1]=v[j];
            j--;
        }
        v[j+1]=key;
    }
        if(f == 0) {
            return new Voter[0];
        }
        else
            return v;
    }
static int findTotal(Voter voters[],String s){
    int c=0;
    for(Voter voter:voters){
        if(voter.isVoteCasted() && voter.getConstituency().equals(s)){
            c++;
        }
    }
    return c;
}

}
```

** Voter Class**

```
public class Voter {
 private int voterId;
 private String voterName;
 private int voterAge;
 private String constituency;
 private boolean isVoteCasted;
 public int getVoterId() {
 return voterId;
}
public void setVoterId(int voterId) {
  this.voterId = voterId;
}
public String getVoterName() {
 return voterName;
}
public void setVoterName(String voterName) {
  this.voterName = voterName;
}
public int getVoterAge() {
   return voterAge;
 }
public void setVoterAge(int voterAge) {
  this.voterAge = voterAge;
 }
public String getConstituency() {
  return constituency;
}
public void setConstituency(String constituency) {
  this.constituency = constituency;
}
public boolean isVoteCasted() {
  return isVoteCasted;
}
public void setVoteCasted(boolean isVoteCasted) {
  this.isVoteCasted = isVoteCasted;
}
}
```

Comment: Apart from the usual “what is a NullPointerException and how do I fix it” I’d like to mention two things: 1. If you can, use a recent version of the JDK, it will give you better diagnostic messages for NPEs, and 2. please give Mr Dijkstra back the ‘k’ in his name.

Comment: sir actually its not about dijkstra algorithm . Here i am trying to sort an array of those objects  only whose age <30 . I know we can use Collections but i want to do this using insertion sort , please help me in this sir . For this sir in searchvoterByAge function i made a new array and then copied those objects only whose age < 30 and then trying to implement insertion sort , but then it is giving error